# Python's `urlparse`: Adding GET keywords to a URL

Tags: python, url, urlparse

I'm doing this:

```
urlparse.urljoin('http://example.com/mypage', '?name=joe')
```

And I get this:

```
'http://example.com/?name=joe'
```

While I want to get this:

```
'http://example.com/mypage?name=joe'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by bundling Python 2.6's `urlparse` module with my project. I also had to bundle `namedtuple` which was defined in `collections`, since `urlparse` uses it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use urlparse.urlunparse :

```
import urlparse
parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com/mypage'))
parsed[4] = 'name=joe'
urlparse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing [a known bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1432) which affects Python 2.4-2.6.

If you can't change or patch your version of Python, [@jd's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232743/pythons-urlparse-adding-get-keywords-to-a-url/5233046#5233046) will work around the issue.

However, if you need a more generic solution that works as a standard `urljoin` would, you can use a wrapper method which implements the workaround for that specific use case, and default to the standard `urljoin()` otherwise.

For example:

```
import urlparse

def myurljoin(base, url, allow_fragments=True):
    if url[0] != "?": 
        return urlparse.urljoin(base, url, allow_fragments)
    if not allow_fragments: 
        url = url.split("#", 1)[0]
    parsed = list(urlparse.urlparse(base))
    parsed[4] = url[1:] # assign params field
    return urlparse.urlunparse(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure?  On Python 2.7:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.urljoin('http://example.com/mypage', '?name=joe')
'http://example.com/mypage?name=joe'
```

Comment: Damn, it seems to be a Python 2.5 bug! It's fixed in Python 2.6. What can I do? I can't upgrade to 2.6, this is on GAE.

Comment: I can confirm that it works as expected on Python 2.3 but not 2.4.